# Help me find the name of this collectible card game with unusual mechanics

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember watching a video a while back about a (I think it is a collectible) card game that had some really strange and interesting mechanics. I can't find the video anymore so I was wondering if somebody knows what the game is called. In the video, some MTG or Yu-gi-oh player - can't remember which one - that hasn't played the game was shown cards and had to take a guess how good they are. Here's what I remember about the cards shown:

1. One of the cards was called something like 'christmas gift', or at least that was the theme of the card, and I remember it getting a bonus effect if you play the card in december. Something like 'Draw an extra card if it is currently december.'
2. For another card you could choose to do an evil laugh while playing it, and if you do, it also gains some bonus effect.

There isn't much more I remember, just that it had some really odd mechanics that you wouldn't see in other games. Does anybody know what it's called?

Comment: About 15 years ago, a friend of mine had a Magic the Gathering deck with a James Bond parody theme. It seems like it could fit your description. Also, completely different, the children's game "Elixir" could fit your description.

Comment: Munchkin is known for having additional accessories with different abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you were looking at silver-bordered Magic the Gathering cards?  These non-tournament-legal cards often included mechanics that wouldn't be used in normal sets.

Your example #1 sounds like the holiday promo card [Some Disassembly Required](https://scryfall.com/card/hho/17/some-disassembly-required).  I couldn't find a good match for example #2, but it sounds like the sort of thing that might have been printed in an Un- set.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be [Holiday Fluxx](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/162378/holiday-fluxx)? Those kind of things sound like the wacky rules modification cards that exist in Fluxx games.

Comment: That's not quite it. The game I am thinking about is much closer to the usual collectible card games like MTG, Yu-gi-oh or Hearthstone. There are spells and creatures like in those games. The christmas card is a bit odd, but the game still had a fantasy setting similar to the other ones

Comment: Fluxx games can be combined to some degree, so maybe a mix?

Answer (score 0):

It might be [Sentinels of the Multiverse](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/102652/sentinels-multiverse), specifically the [Guise deck](https://sentinelswiki.com/index.php?title=Guise).  Sentinels has cards which stay in play and function a bit like enchantments, artifacts, and creatures, but also things that resolve and go to the discard pile when played (one-shot) like an instant/sorcery.  So that might be where the familiarity with magic comes in.

Now, Guise is the Sentinels equivalent of Deadpool, so he does weird 4th wall breaking things.  One of his cards says:

> If you throw your hands in the air and yell, "Woo!" you may play a card.

Which might be what you were thinking of when you remembered an evil laugh.  In other words, some out of game action allows you to do an additional thing in game.

The Christmas theme could be because of the "Santa Guise" character variant, which allows you to put people's cards face down on the field, and flip them up later (like opening presents).